# How to undo a mistake in sudoers file?

Tags: linux, sudo

I accidentally command the root admin and sudo in `sudo visduo` file.

Now with current user it is not rolling it back because I can't access it any more.

File does not get opened with command `sudo visudo` It says: user is not in sudoers file.

While if I access it by `nano /etc/sudoers` It says permission denied when I try to save the file again.

```
$sudo cat /etc/sudoers
...
# User privilege Information

#root ALL=(ALL) ALL

#...
#%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

#Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
```

Comment: Login as root and fix it. Failing that, you'll need to boot into single-user mode and adjust it that way.

Comment: I am using root user.

Comment: Then you don't need `sudo`. Just run `visudo` normally. Or, even `vi /etc/sudoers`. If you messed up permissions, use `chmod 660 /etc/sudoers` first.

Comment: it says Permission denied :(

Comment: Time for single user mode. Depending on your distro, the instructions are different, so look that up and you should be able to access it.

Comment: While Chomd "chmod: changing permissions of `/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18288/discussion-between-nathan-c-and-sarz).

Comment: To be honest I am working with our test server (online in-house) many things will messed up

Comment: @Sarz, give us the result of this command: ls -la /etc/sudoers It will help us help you.

Comment: @gmarintes "-r--r----- 1 root root 727 Oct 30 17:34 /etc/sudoers"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changed sudoers file and can't open it anymore; can't open any file using root](https://superuser.com/questions/15639/changed-sudoers-file-and-cant-open-it-anymore-cant-open-any-file-using-root)

Answer (score 0):

Use shellshock to send an echo to `/etc/passwd` (or sudoers(But, I don't know how difficult it would be to Remove a comment. I thought echo could only add)) to create a user with identifier 0. unlimited access root or not. How one would create such a carefully crafted command is beyond me.

Alternatively, it could very well be possible to chroot into it from a live environment and edit sudoers from there. Not sure because yo said that even root couldn't get in. I don't know how catastrophic it would be to `env x='() { :;}; rm /etc/passwd' bash -c "You've done it now"` I also don't know if your distro provides the means to `cp /etc/skel/sudoers /etc/sudoers`

Very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/15639/changed-sudoers-file-and-cant-open-it-anymore-cant-open-any-file-using-root?rq=1). The solution could be there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can login with the 'root' user, you only need to do this:

```
chmod 644 /etc/sudoers
```

This will allow the 'root' user to modify the /etc/sudoers file.
After this, you only need to:

```
nano /etc/sudoers
```

and save your changes.

Comment: It says "chmod: changing permissions of `/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted" :(

Comment: Tell me the result of these two commands: 'whoami' and 'id root'

Comment: Actually its root user is off and we were accessing by doing 'sudo bash' from user softAgent. whoami = softagent and id root = 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: Like what the others said, you'll need to login as root user for you fix this.

Comment: My softagent is with same privileges as root I just logged into recovery mode although it is just read-only mode, but i can not run any of sudo command

Comment: What is the result of 'id softagent'? I am not sure what you meant by 'same privileges as root', but the point is, the sudoers file has -r--r----- 1 root root permissions/owner/group. Not even the root user has write access to the /etc/sudoers file. If you cannot use sudo to change the permission of the /etc/sudoers file, then you have no other choice but to login as root to change the permission.

Comment: Sorry if am not getting your point. id softagent gives "uid=1000(softagent) gid=1000(softagent) groups=1000(softagent) ,0(root),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),110(sambashare),111(admin)
"
What i meant is Softagent user are given same role/permissions/owner/group as root. I modified sudoers file with this user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18304/discussion-between-gmarintes-and-sarz).